# PyAudio install and use it

Tags: python, importerror, pyaudio

I installed pyaudio and the command line tells me, that it worked:

[image: img]

However, if I run my python code which has a Import pyaudio I always get an Import error saying that there is no module named pyaudio.

Can you help me?

Comment: You installed the package for python2, does you code target this version, not the python3 ? You may add some code sample to let us check what happen

Comment: Yes, my code is as well in python2, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a python._pth next to your python.exe, rename it zpython._pth